# Android Emulator Shell Scripting with Ruby

Tags: android, ruby

We are developing a ruby script that executes a bunch of shell commands to launch the emulator and run some calabash tests.

```
PID = fork do
    Signal.trap('HUP') { puts 'PROCESS ENDED'; exit }
    exec 'emulator -avd TestDevice1'
end

fork do
    sleep(55)
    exec 'adb shell input keyevent 82'
end

fork do
    sleep(60)
    exec 'calabash-android run ~/MyApp/MyApp.apk'
    Process.Kill('HUP', PID)
end
```

We are currently using sleep commands so that the calabash tests don't run until the emulator is fully ready. This is not ideal. Is there an Android command to check if the device is ready? By that I mean Android has booted up and the lock screen is displayed.

Comment: adb devices gives you a list of connected devices. the device should not be visible until quite ready

Comment: adb devices command is correct to an extent as the status goes from 'offline' to 'device'. However the 'device' status is visible whilst the android boot screen is still on (well before the lock screen appears).

Comment: if you known of a process that is started when the lock screen is visble, you can adb shell ps |grep

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way I have found to detect if the emulator is ready for use, and for Calabash to start the installation process, is to detect when the `bootanim` has stopped.

You can check whether the emulator has finished booting manually with using ADB in a terminal:

`adb shell getprop init.svc.bootanim`

I have the following in a Rake command as part of a Calabash test suite which does the trick:

```
booting = ''

while booting != 'stopped'
  booting = `adb shell getprop init.svc.bootanim`.strip
  puts 'Waiting for emulator to boot'
  sleep 2
end
```

Hope it works for you!